# Rails: 2 models, 1 table. Separate forms + controllers. After active record validation errors form renders wrong model/incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, erb, form-for

I have 2 models (`pass` and `subscription`), 2 controllers, and 2 forms. The models share a database table.

The shared table is `passes`. To tell a if a record is a `subscription` there is a column `is_subscription`. Thus, I have the below for my `subscription` model:

```
      self.table_name = :passes
      default_scope { where(is_subscription: true) }
      validates :name, presence: true
```

Notice the validation on `name`.

The `subscription` form:

`<%= form_for(@subscription, html: {class: "my-class"}) do |f| %>`

which renders:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="new_subscription" action="/subscriptions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="subscription[name]" id="subscription_name">
...
```

In the controller:

```
  def show
  end

  def new
    @subscription = Subscription.new
  end

  def create
    @subscription = current_user.company.passes.new(subscription_params)
    if @subscription.save
      redirect_to subscription_path(@subscription), notice: "Yay"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Everything works great. But if I attempt to create a new subscription and omit `name` from the form - this triggers the active record validation and an error. The form re-renders and now has changed:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="new_pass" action="/passes" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="pass[name]" id="pass_name">
...
```

I have tried setting `as: "subscription"` which fixes everything except for the action. If I set `action:` the action is still overridden.

Would appreciate some insight on how to best handle this. Unfortunately,  I do not have the ability to change the table situtation (ie use separate tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you create a Pass when you submit a Subscription (you say you have 2 controllers but it looks like you are using only one controller for both (?)).

I would just set a Subscription object if the Pass can't be saved:

```
def create
  @subscription = Pass.new(subscription_params)
  if @subscription.save
    redirect_to subscription_path(@subscription), notice: "Yay"
  else
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
    render :new
  end
end
```

That way you'll have a subscription on the variable you are using.

EDIT: also, check activerecord's support for Single Table Inheritance, it could help you clean up the model https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: sorry, the controller actually has: `current_user.company.passes.new(subscription_params)`. I have updated the question to reflect this. There are certainly 2 controllers :)

Comment: @user3574076 you can still use the idea of creating a new Subscription object if the pass can't be saved, doesn't that work for you?

Comment: If you need the object's error hash populated you can call `@subscription.valid?` too

Comment: So I just tried this out. It does solve the initial issue, thank you! However, now the active record validations (errors) are wiped out. Which is resolved by `@subscription.valid?`. However, now I no longer have `<%= f.error_notification %>` rendering any error messages (the field errors are populating though). 

Its certainly a big improvment, so I will mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: Seems like `error_notifications` will only show up if I use `current_user.company.passes.new(subscription_params)`. But then the original issue persists. An acceptable trade off for now I guess

Answer (score 1):

You could use `form_tag` instead of `form_for`. The former doesn't care about the model object being used - in fact you don't even pass it in. This would require you to use the generic `text_field_tag`, etc helpers instead of `form.text_field :foo` that you might be using now.

But it will allow you to side-step this issue.